# How to get parameter from php url and use for query result

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new in php and I don't know how to execute SQL query for where clause with php parameter from url please help me.

**Url:** http://myurl.com/eng.php?name=fab

**PHP Code**

```
 <?php
 header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 $mysqli = new mysqli ( 'localhost', 'mabhim92', '9993115300', 'gcm_chat');
 //PROBLEM LANGUAGE ?????
if( function_exists('mysql_set_charset') ){
mysqli_set_charset($mysqli , 'utf8');
}else{
 mysqli_query($mysqli , "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
}
 // Check if album id is posted as GET parameter
$id = intval($_GET['name']);
$myq = $mysqli ->query ("SELECT * FROM  gkfordate WHERE monthforgk=$id");   
   while ($myr = $myq->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array["Questions"][] = (array(   
    'month'      => $myr['monthforgk'],
    'date' => $myr['dateforgk'],
     ));
  }
  echo json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
   ?>
```

**Result**: In my database table only two columns monthforgk and dateforgk

```
{
 "Questions": [
{
  "month": "jan",
  "date": "2016-04-13 20:30:49"
},
{
  "month": "jan",
  "date": "2016-04-13 20:30:49"
},
{
  "month": "jan",
  "date": "2016-04-13 20:30:49"
},
{
  "month": "fab",
  "date": "2016-04-13 20:30:49"
},
{
  "month": "fab",
  "date": "2016-04-13 20:30:49"
}
]
}
```

If I pass parameter for name=fab so why give me all result from database.

Comment: what you want to get

Comment: If your `monthforgk` values are strings - `jan`/`fab`, etc, then why are you doing `$id = intval($_GET['name']);`? You are basically doing `... WHERE monthforgk=1`

Comment: please see query  result for monthforgk = fab.

Comment: @Sean so what can I do result only for monthforgk = fab using param

Comment: instead of `$id = intval($_GET['name']);` you would do [`$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['name']);`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) (to sanitize the `$_GET`).  And then quote the value in your query -> `... WHERE monthforgk= '$id' "`, as the value is a string, not an int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you try with query

```
"SELECT * FROM  gkfordate WHERE monthforgk='$id'";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are running the query string through the intval() function, which returns the integer value of the string 'fab' which is 0.

Try this:

```
echo 'intval of fab = '.intval('fab');
```

What you need is simply this:

```
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
}
```

And then in the query:

```
$myq = $mysqli ->query ("SELECT * FROM  gkfordate WHERE monthforgk='$id'");
```

Comment: It would be better if you recommended [`$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['name']);`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) instead of `$id = $_GET['name'];`